# ebXml OpenSource java implementation

Tags: open-source, registry, repository, b2b, ebxml

In our project we are looking for an OpenSource java implementation of the OASIS ebXml Registry 3.0 Specification ([spec](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/regrep/)).
It seems there is not a lot of OpenSource initiative for this standard, actually we only found [freebXml Registry](http://ebxmlrr.sourceforge.net/) which is self-named Reference implementation of the specification.

The last release (3.1) is from 2007... and it does not seem to be a lot of activity in the different forums and bug tracking sections.

Do you guys know a little bit more about this particular project?

More generally do you know if there is another implementation available?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is also the OHF project. It uses its own registry implementation.