# ActiveMQ support for ebXML as message broker

Tags: apache, activemq-classic, ebxml

Currently I am researching open source message broker technology that can provide support for ebXML I would like to use Apache ActiveMQ.

I will be looking at supporting Oasis ebXML AS4 specification.

My question is, does Apache ActiveMQ as a JMS broker offer adequate support for ebXML, in particular ebXML 3 AS4?
Are there any alternative open source message broker technology more suited to ebXML?

Lastly is there a .NET interface library to support ebXML support via ActiveMQ?

Thanks in advance,

Marcus

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "support"?

Apache ActiveMQ is a messaging component. It does not really care about the content in the messages, but should merly be seen as a transport channel.

Apache Camel comes bundle with ActiveMQ do support XML (parsing, transforming), but not ebXML explicitly.

Typically, explicit support for these industry standard EDI formats are rarely implemented in open source middleware. There might be some old java library open source out there ( [ebXml OpenSource java implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644237/ebxml-opensource-java-implementation?rq=1) ), but nothing very active, unfortunately.